# subquery in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
insert into nt_nurture_profile (credit,user_id,wallet_key)
values (0, select person_id from ct_student where person_id not in(select user_id from nt_nurture_profile), gen_random_uuid ());
```

this is my code but ran into an error

```
syntax error at or near "select"
```

but when i use select in single line it works!

Answer (score 1):

The below select statements works

```
insert into nt_nurture_profile (credit,user_id,wallet_key)
select 0, person_id, gen_random_uuid ()
  from ct_student 
  where person_id not in(select user_id from nt_nurture_profile));
```

Comment: If by "fill all the values manually" you mean that `VALUES` does not support subqueries, then this answer is wrong (although the code portion is fine).

Comment: Correct, I reworded the reply